# How do I fill a blank matrix given conditions from a refernce dataframe?

Tags: r, matrix, conditional-formatting

I am trying to organize a matrix showing which individuals in a trapping set were caught together.
Currently I have a blank matrix where the rows and columns are named after each individual in the data set

```
my_sociomatrix = matrix(, nrow = 389, ncol = 389)
diag(my_sociomatrix) <- 0

names_list<- unique(df$individual)
names_list
rownames(my_sociomatrix)<-names_list
colnames(my_sociomatrix)<-names_list
```

What I want to do is assign a "1,2,3… or 0" depending on how many times individuals were caught together.

I have a separate data frame with the information needed for determining which individuals were caught in each trapping event. Some individuals were caught multiple times so they appear more than once.

| individual | trap event |
| --- | --- |
| NA002 | A |
| NA03,41 | A |
| NA03,42 | B |
| NA03,41 | C |
| NA03,42 | C |
| NA03,43 | C |
| NA002 | D |
| NA03,41 | D |
| NA03,44 | D |
| NA03,45 | D |

I want to fill out the matrix using the reference of the data frame so the matrix would fill out like this. I can't do this by hand since the full matrix is 389x389 cells.

|  | NA002 | NA03,41 | NA03,42 | NA03,43 | NA03,44 | NA03,45 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA002 | - |  |  |  |  |  |
| NA03,41 | 2 | - |  |  |  |  |
| NA03,42 | 0 | 1 | - |  |  |  |
| NA03,43 | 0 | 1 | 1 | - |  |  |
| NA03,44 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | - |  |
| NA03,45 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | - |

Individual NA002 and NA03,41 were caught together twice so they would get assigned a 2. Individual NA002 and NA03,42 were never caught together so they get a 0. And individual NA002 and NA03,44 were caught together once, so they get a 1, and so on...

How do I fill out my matrix using conditions based on my dataframe? I have use R for a few years, but this type of work is all new to me as I have never had to work with matrixes before.

I was thinking of using the basic

`net[,]=` but with an ifelse statement, but am unsure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets the frequency for individuals sharing trap event

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyverse)
df = data.frame(individual = c("NA002","NA03,41","NA03,42","NA03,41","NA03,42","NA03,43","NA002","NA03,41","NA03,44","NA03,45"),"trap event" = c("A","A","B","C","C","C","D","D","D","D"))

      df %>% mutate(n = 1) %>% 
      spread(individual, n, fill=0) %>% 
      select(-trap_event) %>% 
      {crossprod(as.matrix(.))} %>% 
      `diag<-`(0)
```

Output:

```
       NA002 NA03,41 NA03,42 NA03,43 NA03,44 NA03,45
NA002       0       2       0       0       1       1
NA03,41     2       0       1       1       1       1
NA03,42     0       1       0       1       0       0
NA03,43     0       1       1       0       0       0
NA03,44     1       1       0       0       0       1
NA03,45     1       1       0       0       1       0
```

Comment: I am unsure why but the code error I receive is "Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')"

Comment: I added reference to the data frame but it still won't run.                                     my_sociomatrix %>% mutate(n = 1) %>% 
  spread(df$individual, n, fill=0) %>% 
  select(-df$trap_event) %>% 
  {crossprod(as.matrix(.))} %>% 
  `diag<-`(0)

Comment: You dont need to reference using $ in dplyr, ive edited the code. Input your data frame (which i called df) containing the two columns Individual and trap event before the pipe %>%. This will output a dataframe as shown and if you want to convert to a matrix do as.matrix(). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you cgvoller, your code was great. Here is the slightly edited code for anyone interested. If you can't write out your df in one line subset your original df so it only has the two columns you need.

````
df2 <- Rsnappers[, c("trap_event", "individual")]
head(df2)

df2 %>% mutate(n = 1) %>% 
  spread(individual, n, fill=0) %>% 
  select(-trap_event) %>% 
  {crossprod(as.matrix(.))} %>% 
  `diag<-`(0)

#add to matrix
my_sociomatrix <- df2 %>% mutate(n = 1) %>% 
  spread(individual, n, fill=0) %>% 
  select(-trap_event) %>% 
  {crossprod(as.matrix(.))} %>% 
  `diag<-`(0)```
````